# Excel graph using stacks

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I need to develop a stacked graph based on time intervals:

Basically I have 10 different time intervals and I want to display all the values that I have stacked on this time interval, for example:

Dataset example to plot the graph:

```
Time interval    -    Name of the group   -   Number of jobs
2 minutes                  Group A                  5
2 minutes                  Group B                  10
2 minutes                  Group C                  15
4 minutes                  Group A                  10
4 minutes                  Group D                  5
6 minutes                  Group B                  25
6 minutes                     ..                    ..
6 minutes
8 minutes
10 minutes
10 minutes
10 minutes                    ..                    ..
10 minutes                 Group A                  10
```

So basically I want my X axis as the time interval (2,4,6 minutes..)
And on each bar of the time interval I want to stack the group values with a legend for the name of each group.

So on time interval of 2 minutes I would like to have a total stacked bar with value 30 (5+10+15) and this bar would need 3 different colors for each group inside (Groups A,B and C)

Is it clear?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You will want To rearrange your data like this:

[image]

You can then easily generate a stacked column chart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to organize you data in a matrix where the colums' titles are the groups and the rows' titles are the time interval values.
For that, you can use Pivot Table.

1. select all the data cells (including thetitles in the first line).
2. click the Add tab, click PivotTable.
3. Choose Where to place the Pivot Table(I prefer in the same sheet,
   but when there's a lot of data it might be better to place it in a
   new sheet).
4. in the left panel "PivotTable fields", drag "Time Interval" into
   "columuns", "Name of the Group" into "rows" and "Number of jobs"
   into "values".
5. because pivot table is acctually used for counting and summing, in
   addition to the matrix there will be grand total values which you
   can (and should) remove by right click on "Grand Total" and then
   "remove Grand Total" (you acctually should do it twice, one for the
   row grand total and one for the column grand total).
6. There might be other annoying titles such as "Sum of Number of jobs"
   and "column titles", don't worry you can edit those title cells like
   any other cell.
7. finally, select all the data in the matrix (include the groups'
   names and the time intervals), click the Add tab and click the bars
   chart icon and click the stacked bars chart icon.

Done!

let me know if this solved your problem or if misunderstood the problem right.

Good Luck!